# Incompatible pointer types assigning to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm just trying to make some kind of pointer to "Nall" struct so I wrote this code

```
Nall **headall;
    headall = malloc (30000 * sizeof (Nall));
    for (i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
        *(headall+i) = newNall;
    }
```

and now I get this error

> "warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to `Nall *`
>         (aka `struct nodeall *`) from `Nall *(void)`
>         (aka `struct nodeall *(void)`) [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>           `*(headall+i) = newNall;`"

Comment: How is `newNall` defined?  It is a variable or a function?

Comment: Your allocation is suspicious.  `headall` has type `Nall **`, but you compute the size of the allocation in terms of type `Nall`.  One would ordinarily expect it to be computed in terms of the size of the type to which `headall` points, *i.e.* **`Nall *`**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the compiler warning I'm assuming that `newNall` is actually a function that allocates a new `struct nodeall` and returns a pointer to it. In that case, your code should look like this:

```
Nall **headall;
headall = malloc(30000 * sizeof *headall);
for (i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
  headall[i] = newNall();
```

Note the argument to the `sizeof` operator, and the parentheses after `newNall`.